# Pass multiple parameters to BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, begininvoke

I have simple (as i think) logic.

```
public static void NotifyAboutNewJob(int jobId, bool forceSending = false)
{
        Action<int> notifier = SendAppleNotifications;
        notifier.BeginInvoke(jobId, null, null);
}
```

Method SendAppleNotifications had one parametera and it was easy to pass it into `BeginInvoke`. Now i have added second parameter `forceSending`. And problem - i don't know how to pass it into `BeginInvoke`.

Should i pass it as 3rd param as `object` ?

```
private static void SendAppleNotifications(int jobId, bool forceSending = false){...}
```

Or this is the answer :

```
Action<int, bool> notifier = SendAppleNotifications;
notifier.BeginInvoke(jobId, forceSending, null, null);
```

Comment: You could also implement it like this: `Task.Run(() => SendAppleNotifications(jobId, forceSending));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your `Action<int>` to `Action<int, bool>`

```
Action<int, bool> notifier = SendAppleNotifications;
notifier.BeginInvoke(jobId, forceSending, null, null); // You can now pass true or false as 2nd parameter.
```

then it should work ok.